# If the derivative of a function is irrational does it follow that the original function is irrational?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponentiation, irrational-numbers

I'm in my final year of secondary school in Ireland and was thinking about powers of irrational numbers with rational solutions and very quickly noticed that $(x^\frac{1}{a})^a$ where $x\in Q$ and $a \notin Q$  was always rational.

I wanted to prove that $x^\frac{1}{a} \notin Q$

And this was as far as I got

$$
f(x) = x^b,\ \ x\in Q,\ \ b\notin Q, \ \ x\ne0\\
f'(x) = bx^{b-1}\\
\therefore \ \ f'(x) \notin Q
$$

if I can deduce from that $f(x)$ is also irrational then I can deduce that $x^\frac{1}{a} \notin Q$ where $x\ne0$

In my head this should be fine as if the function always changes by an irrational number it should ultimately be irrational, but I cant find a way too prove it, or a source verifying this.

Am I allowed make that deduction and is there anything else flawed in my reasoning?

Comment: Numbers can be rational or irrational, but not functions. And there is no relationship between derivatives and rationality I know of. And $x^{1/a}$ is not always irrational; take $x=1$ or $x=2^a$ for example

Comment: I believe your  general claim (assuming I understand it) is false.  Consider $f(x)=x^2-\pi^2$.  Then $f'(\pi)=2\pi$ is irrational, but $f(\pi)=0$ is rational.  Or have I mistaken your meaning?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. For your original problem you may be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem#Statement) theorem.

Comment: It seems like "$\therefore f'(x)\notin Q$" comes from the (mistaken) belief that $x^c\notin Q$ if $c\notin Q,x\in Q$, but if you already believe that then you can believe $f(x)\notin Q$ as well (which is false in general)

Comment: " very quickly noticed that $(x^\frac{1}{a})^a$ where x∈Q and a∉Q was always rational"  Well, that's because $(x^{\frac 1a})^a = x \in \mathbb Q$.  There's nothing deep about that.  "I wanted to prove that $x^{\frac 1a}∉Q$".  What if $x = 1$? @pancini your counter example of $2^a$ is only a counter example if $2^a$ is rational.  Which, if I understand, J.G.'s Gelford Schneider's Theorem, it can not ever be.  I think if we omit $x=0,1$ the O.P.'s conjecture is correct but for none of the reasons given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement that $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $a \notin \mathbb{Q}$ implies $x^{\frac{1}{a}} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ is false. Here's a counter-example:

Let
$$
x = 2, a = \frac{1}{\log_2(3)}
$$

Then $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a \notin \mathbb{Q}$, but
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x^{\frac{1}{a}} =& 2^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\log_2(3)}}}\\
=& 2^{\log_2(3)} \\
=& 3 \\
\in& \mathbb{Q}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Also $x=1$ works

Comment: I dont know why I didnt think of that counter example, the issue stemmed from an issue where a is equal to $\pi$ does it apply in that situation?

Comment: What about $x = 0$?